# Extraccion de imagenes con Script como hacer?

Tags: php, javascript, linux, cmd

alguien sabe como puedo  extraer imágenes con un script de una carpeta o ruta, teniendo un listado de excel con su respectivo nombre, pero si quiero sacar solo 5 pues en el script debería tener los 5 nombres y asi sucesivamente sin tener que extraer todo o una por una?

Soy novato en Programación.

Comment: El archivo de Excel, que estructura tiene?, es un simple archivo de texto con listas o es una tabla con informacion adicional?

Comment: Es un excel con una columna has de cuenta que tienes en esa columna 150 registros y en una carpeta tienes 1500 imágenes y dentro de esta carpeta están tus 150 registros cómo puedo extraer esas 150 de las mil 500 con un script

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. No me queda para nada claro lo que pretendes, ya que mencionas php y javascript, tu queres ¿_extraer_ imágenes del lado del cliente? ¿del lado del servidor?, ¿qué es exactamente _extraer_ una imagen? Hablando en términos más claros, podría ser obtener el nombre de archivo, la ruta completa del archivo, cargar los datos en memoria, o quizás incluir la imagen en una etiqueta `<img>` de tu `HTML`. Te invito a leer [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), y luego editar tu pregunta, pues eso aumentará tus posibilidades de obtener ayuda.